# How to use the new "route" command from OSRM v5? (Formerly "viaroute")

Tags: osrm

Under version v4 I used `http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?loc=47.168,8.117&loc=46.978,8.335&instructions=true` to access routes. Now it just returns

> The OSRM Demo server has moved to API Version 5. Documentation for the
>   new version can be found at
>   https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/docs/http.md

How does that translate to the new version v5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The follwing line works: `http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/8.117,47.168;8.33,46.978?steps=true`.

**Note** that the order of `lat`/`lng` changed!

However, the server seems to be down quite frequently at the moment.